# Download specific file on page loading using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, indexing, download

I'm trying to let my `.htaccess` file to force the download a specific `*.zip` file contained in the root of the website.

Basically, loading my page the user will download automatically my `*.zip` file without even seeing the Directory Listing.

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
### MAIN DEFAULTS
Options +ExecCGI -Indexes
DirectoryIndex file.zip
DefaultLanguage en-US
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
ServerSignature Off

### FORCE FILE TO DOWNLOAD INSTEAD OF APPEAR IN BROWSER
AddType application/octet-stream .zip
AddType application/zip .zip
```

I can download the file, but the latter has no extension and it's called `download`.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

-RJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to the end of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Header set Content-disposition "attachment; filename=file.zip;"
```